# How to to make base shape with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make base shape with css since I need to add it to homepage of the website. The final version is attached below with the image. 
Please help me out, I'm not really sure how to achieve this

[image: CSS shape]

```css
#base {
  background: #0a863d;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 55px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 55px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
#base:before {
  border-bottom: 35px solid #0a863d;
  border-left: 50px solid transparent;
  border-right: 50px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: -35px;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="base"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change borders for `:after` element:

```css
#base {
  background: #0a863d;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 60px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 55px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
#base:before {
    border-left: 30px solid #0a863d;
    border-top: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    right: -30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="base"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#base {
  background: #0a863d;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 55px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 55px;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}

#base:after {
  content: "";
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 27.5px 0 27.5px 25px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #0a863d;
  position: absolute;
  right: -25px;
}
```

```html
<div id="base"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
#base {
  background: #0a863d;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 55px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
#base:before {
  border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
  border-left: 50px solid #0a863d;
  border-top: 25px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  left:100%;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="base"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make use of the `::before` pseudo element.

```css
#base {
  background: #0a863d;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 55px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 55px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100px;
}
#base:before {
      border-bottom: 27px solid transparent;
    border-left: 30px solid #0a863d;
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-top: 28px solid transparent;
    content: "";
    height: 0;
    right: -60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="base"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can rotate the arrow by changing the `margin` and `border` properties: they have to be "rotated" to the right (`left` becomes `top`, `top` becomes `right`, and so on):

```css
#base {
  background: #0a863d;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 66px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-right: 55px;
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
}
#base:before {
  border-left: 35px solid #0a863d;
  border-top: 33px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 33px solid transparent;
  content: "";
  height: 0;
  top: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: -35px;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="base"></div>
```

The *height* of the arrow can be changed by adjusting the `height` of the `#base` and the `border-top` and `border-bottom` of `#base:before`. (Note that the sum of `border-top` and `border-bottom` should be the same as the `height`.)
The *width* of the arrow can be changed by adjusting the `width` of the `#base`